# How do I say no brainer in Russian?

Tags: phrase

A ["no brainer"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22was%20a%20no%20brainer%22) is something so clear and obvious that it takes little to no thinking to make a decision, it is definetely not worth the effort to be thinking harder about. How do I say it in Russian?

Answer (score 7):

In Russian it could be:

- Slang: `Ежу понятно` (`Коню понятно` etc).
- `Проще простого`.

Comment: Also 'it was a no brainer' - было [совершенно] очевидным.

Comment: @YellowSky No. That's not a translation. That's an explanation in another language. I second *ежу понятно*.

Comment: A less — how should I put it — fruity one, but not less expressive (and a bit grumpy), would be *дурак и тот поймёт*. (No comma needed.)

Comment: What is the image of a hedgehog in Russian that gives rise to this? Are they imagined to be dumb animals?

Comment: @KCd - There're 2 versions, it can be a quote from the 1925 poem by Mayakovsky, "Сказка о Пете, толстом ребенке, и о Симе, который тонкий": «Ясно даже и ежу — / Этот Петя был буржуй». According to the other version, in the Soviet specialised schools for gifted children there were classes А, Б, В, Г, and Д for those who had to study 2 more years, and Е, Ж, И for 1 year, the pupils in the latter were called "ежи", and when they only started their studying in those schools the former pupils had already been there for a year and were more educated. Here: http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=14.77

Comment: Yellow Sky Wow i've never knew that! I've studied in a school that just had too much classes and labeled up to "Ж" and there was no such differences. Maybe because it was just common soviet school.

Comment: By the way, hedgehog is not only one used for this saying; in our family we say "козе понятно" :)

Answer (score 4):

We have a lot sentences with the same meaning:

- К бабке не ходи
- И ежу понятно
- Естественно
- Само собой
- etc.

Comment: + К гадалке не ходи, Разумеется, Понятное дело

Answer (score 3):

You could also say «Ясное дело!» или «Ясен пень!» (which is a jargon version of the first) but the more appropriate phrase of all listed in the answers depends on the context.

```
− Смотри не пожодги газовый баллон.
− Ясное дело — взорвется ведь!
− Взорвется, это и ежу понятно.
```

Comment: While this expression obviously exists I do not think promoting (potentially short-lived) jargon is particularly productive here. The expression itself is a jargon version of *ясное дело* - literally, *a clear matter*.

Answer (score 1):

Ежу понятно - it is correct, and colloquial.
Other options:

- не бином Ньютона (maybe slightly bookish)
- не требует большого ума (stylistically neutral)

Comment: "Козе понятно".

Answer (score 1):

- *Даже ребёнку понятно.*
- *И дураку понятно.*

Answer (score 1):

When you refer to the situation of an obvious decision (rather than an a reason or  explanation), a closer translation of "no-brainer" would be like «нечего раздумывать», «тут и думать было нечего» or so.

«Ежу понятно» and other suggested variants can refer to any uncomplicated matter, even when "no-brainer" is hardly applicable («Спасибо, что объяснил. Теперь-то это и ежу понятно!»)